# numpy: create a 2-d coordinate matrix array from two 1-d array as row and column

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays as the coordinates of rows and columns of a matrix:

```
r = np.array([1, 2, 3])
c = np.array([7, 8, 9])
```

Is there a simple way to create a new array of the coordinates of all cells of the matrix, like:

```
m = np.SOME_FUNCTION(r, c)
# m = array([[1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9]])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
m = np.c_[np.meshgrid(r, c)].T.reshape(-1, 2)
```

Or [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
m = np.c_[np.repeat(r, len(c)), np.tile(c, len(r))]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 7],
       [1, 8],
       [1, 9],
       [2, 7],
       [2, 8],
       [2, 9],
       [3, 7],
       [3, 8],
       [3, 9]])
```